# Firebase query not working as expected React native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a query based on multiple WHERE clauses and it returns true if found and deletes record and false if otherwise. The problem is it adds the new record in the database but automatically deletes it afterwards. When commenting out the remove part it works as expected adding the new record only if not present.

This is my code:

```
var found = false;
firebase.database().ref(`/yums/`)
        .orderByChild('recipeId').equalTo(uid)
        .on('value', snapshot => {
            const likes = snapshot.val();
            for (var like in likes) {
                if (likes[like].userId == currentUser.uid) {
                    found = true;
                    firebase.database().ref(`/yums/`)
                        .child(like).remove();
                }
            }
        })

if (found == false ) {
        firebase.database().ref(`/yums/`)
            .push({ 
                recipeId: uid, 
                userId: currentUser.uid,
                timestamp: Date.now(),
            })
            .then(() => {
                dispatch({ type: YUMMED_SUCCESS });
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

had to replace .on with .once and put the if found statement in a .then() block